# php nested array unset element with key

Tags: php

I need to unset the [device_id] element from the every array.
I tried with recursive. But i am not able to do this. Can any one help on this. I tried like this.

```
foreach($tree as $key) {
    foreach($key as $value => $k){
        if ($value == 'device_id'){
            unset($k['device_id']);
        }
    }   
}
```

I have nested multidimensional array as below:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [device_id] => 4
            [device_parent_id] => 2
            [device_ext] => 20122
            [device_name] => section controller1
            [username] => sectioncontroller1
            [password] => 90714771f0abd448f208e1aff5b662fc
            [device_macaddress] => 
            [device_ip] => 
            [device_desc] => 
            [admin_id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [device_id] => 5
                            [device_parent_id] => 4
                            [device_ext] => 20199
                            [device_name] => Emergency1
                            [username] => Emergency1
                            [password] => bb75df6eb4fdbf5753640a34674ecce1
                            [device_macaddress] => 
                            [device_ip] => 
                            [device_desc] => 
                            [admin_id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [device_id] => 6
                            [device_parent_id] => 4
                            [device_ext] => 20111
                            [device_name] => HQ Phone
                            [username] => HQPhone
                            [password] => 2f89d97f24539dc50ddd8fc53667b194
                            [device_macaddress] => 
                            [device_ip] => 
                            [device_desc] => 
                            [admin_id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [device_id] => 9
                            [device_parent_id] => 4
                            [device_ext] => 20144
                            [device_name] => Other controller1
                            [username] => Othercontroller1
                            [password] => 861426b485e2afd62ad0d914f524f23c
                            [device_macaddress] => 
                            [device_ip] => 
                            [device_desc] => 
                            [admin_id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [10] => Array
                                        (
                                            [device_id] => 10
                                            [device_parent_id] => 9
                                            [device_ext] => 30122
                                            [device_name] => Way Station1
                                            [username] => WayStation1
                                            [password] => 085d397b0392d3a325216a716c757113
                                            [device_macaddress] => 
                                            [device_ip] => 
                                            [device_desc] => 
                                            [admin_id] => 2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [device_id] => 21
            [device_parent_id] => 2
            [device_ext] => 1123299
            [device_name] => sectioncontroller99
            [username] => sectioncontroller3
            [password] => 73d25d443117f76c6fe6bd5a4679f458
            [device_macaddress] => 124511251419
            [device_ip] => 124.235.63.569
            [device_desc] => test section9
            [admin_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [device_id] => 22
                            [device_parent_id] => 21
                            [device_ext] => 9999
                            [device_name] => emergancy
                            [username] => emergancy
                            [password] => c2bc24d3d41ad9ade0171c3d5d6f59c6
                            [device_macaddress] => 1245122
                            [device_ip] => 124.235.235
                            [device_desc] => sdfdf sdfsdf sdfsd
                            [admin_id] => 0
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
);
```

Comment: What do you want to unset?

Comment: [device_id] from every array and nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive function for this. This should work:

```
function deleteDeviceId(&$tree) {
    foreach ($tree as $k => &$item) {
        unset($item['device_id']);
        deleteDeviceId($item['children']);
    }
}

deleteDeviceId($tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variables in the loop are independant variables, changing them does not affect the original array.

To solve that you can either:

- Use the complete path in `$tree` to unset your variable there directly:
   `unset($tree[$outer_key][$inner_key]);`. You would need the key in the outer loop as well.
  Note that you seem to be using key and value the wrong way around in your `foreach` loop but that's just the name...
- Pass the loop variables by reference; when they reference the original variable, any change will be a change in the original variable as well.